# paginate() method in Laravel 5 not working

Tags: pagination, laravel-5

I am working on laravel 5 project. I have stuck on pagination thing. I am trying to access paginate() method, but it says this method is not defined. This is my code where i have used paginate() method

```
 public function show($id){
        $codes = DB::table('soada1s')->where('couponcodefile_id','=', $id)->get()->paginate(10);
        return view('admin',compact('codes'));
    }
```

I have also included below class in my controller

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
```

Please tell me what is wrong?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the exact error message you're getting?

I think you need to use the paginate function just after your where function.

```
 DB::table('soada1s')->where('couponcodefile_id','=', $id)->paginate(10);
```

The get() function will return a collection object, and I don't think you can call the paginate function on a collection object.

Comment: thanks. You are right. it was returning collection object with get, that's why it was not working.